# Google transliteration on keyup

Tags: google-translate

I am using Google transliterate in my application.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("elements", "1", { packages: "transliteration" });
</script>
<script>
    function OnLoad() {
        var options = {
            sourceLanguage:
            google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
            destinationLanguage:
            [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.TAMIL],
            shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
            transliterationEnabled: true
        };
        //farmer name
        var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
        control.makeTransliteratable(["txtFarmer_nameTn"]);
        var keyVal = 32; // Space key
        $("#txtFarmer_nameEng").on('keydown', function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                var engText = $("#txtFarmer_nameEng").val() + " ";
                var engTextArray = engText.split(" ");
                $("#txtFarmer_nameTn").val($("#txtFarmer_nameTn").val() + engTextArray[engTextArray.length - 2]);
                document.getElementById("txtFarmer_nameTn").focus();
                $("#txtFarmer_nameTn").trigger(
                {
                    type: 'keypress', keyCode: keyVal, which: keyVal, charCode: keyVal
                });
            }

            var txt1 = document.getElementById("txtFarmer_nameEng").value;
            if (txt1.length == 1) {
                document.getElementById("txtFarmer_nameTn").value = "";
            }


        });

        $("#txtFarmer_nameTn").bind("keyup", function (event) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#txtFarmer_nameEng").val($("#txtFarmer_nameEng").val() + " ");
                document.getElementById("txtFarmer_nameEng").focus()
            }, 0);
        });
}
 google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>
```

It is also working fine. But the problem is the text was translated only after hit the Space Bar. I need to translate the text on every key press.

Here is the [reference](https://cloud.google.com/translate/)

Please suggest any solution. I was roaming over google, but i can't get the exact solution. Suggest What to use instead of Google Transliterate API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The way which you are going is wrong with Google translate. Google is not allow with dynamically adding tab or space bar key for translate language.

We must be press Tab or Space bar key after written text by physically.

Comment: Okay Pang. I think you are right there is no option what i thinking.